# How to access to the content of an address without using a pointer

Tags: c++

I'm trying to better understand how pointers work, so I coded the example below. Basically, because an address is just a number I thought why not simply store it in a `long q` variable instead of a pointer, it seems to be working as `q` now has the same hex value as the pointer `p`. Now I'm trying to access the content of this long integer variable, I can do `* (int*) q` but I'm wondering if there is a way to access the content of that number without casting the variable `q` with `(int*)`?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x = 9;
    int *p = &x;
    long q = (long) &x;

    cout << p << endl;
    cout << std::hex << q << endl;
}
```

Comment: What language are you really using, C or C++?  And why did you tag this as `C`, when the code has `<iostream>`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Based on `<iostream>` I edited the tag to C++ only.

Comment: *"why not simply store it in a long q"* - because there is no guarantee that a `long` is actually large enough to store an address?

Comment: Take a look at `std::intptr_t`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie preferably C++ but I don't think it matters in this case, otherwise I would love to know the difference.

Comment: @Raftel When you mention `cast`, it makes a world of difference as to the answer you get.  One language has various casts, the other, only one kind of cast.

Comment: You have to cast it to `int`, how other would you get an `int` from it? I mean, a pointer is just indirect access to memory so if you do not want to use a pointer, use assembly instructions instead. Not that it is a good idea.

Comment: @Quimby I'm not trying to avoid using pointers, I just want to learn how things work internally.

Comment: Pointers are built-in types and they make working with memory addresses easier. For example, they support pointer arithmetic something you have to do manually if you store addresses inside integer variables which is error prone.

Comment: @Raftel Pointers are as internal as it gets in C++ apart from the inline assembly.

Comment: @Raftel A `long` could be 4 bytes, while a pointer could be 8 bytes if you are running a 64-bit application.  So right there, your cast isn't going to work for most systems that run 64-bit applications.

Comment: @Raftel `static_assert(sizeof(long) == sizeof(int *));` -- Your code will fail to compile if the assertion is `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Most compilers have an inline assembly feature so you could pass `q` as an argument to a block of assembly code and do whatever you want to it in assembly, including dereferencing it.  There is no point to that, of course, but it is one way to avoid using the pointer feature of the C++ language which is what you asked about.